# Mysterious access violations/skipped statements/silent failure with DIB sections

Tags: winapi, gdi

I'm making a DIB section like this:

```
BITMAPINFO bmi;
bmi.bmiHeader.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFO);
bmi.bmiHeader.biWidth = MY_WIDTH;
bmi.bmiHeader.biHeight = -MY_HEIGHT; // Order pixels from top to bottom
bmi.bmiHeader.biPlanes = 1;
bmi.bmiHeader.biBitCount = 32; // last byte not used, 32 bit for alignment
bmi.bmiHeader.biCompression = BI_RGB;
bmi.bmiHeader.biSizeImage = 0;
bmi.bmiHeader.biXPelsPerMeter = 0;
bmi.bmiHeader.biYPelsPerMeter = 0;
bmi.bmiHeader.biClrUsed = 0;
bmi.bmiHeader.biClrImportant = 0;
bmi.bmiColors[0].rgbBlue = 0;
bmi.bmiColors[0].rgbGreen = 0;
bmi.bmiColors[0].rgbRed = 0;
bmi.bmiColors[0].rgbReserved = 0;

hbm = CreateDIBSection(hdc, &bmi, DIB_RGB_COLORS, (void**)&pixels, NULL, 0);
```

When painting:

```
HDC hdcMem = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);

HBITMAP hbmOld = (HBITMAP)SelectObject(hdcMem, hbm);
onFrame(pixels);
BitBlt(hdc, 0, 0, MY_WIDTH, MY_HEIGHT, hdcMem, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
SelectObject(hdcMem, hbmOld);
DeleteDC(hdcMem);
```

onFrame():

```
void onFrame(pixel *pixels) {
// This is where all the drawing takes place
pixel *p;
// +0.005 each frame
static float frameOffset = 0;
float px; // % of the way across the bitmap
float py; // % of the way down the bitmap
for (int x = 0; x < MY_WIDTH; ++x) {
    for (int y = 0; y < MY_HEIGHT; ++y) {
        p = &pixels[y * MY_WIDTH + x];
        px = float(x) / float(MY_WIDTH);
        py = float(y) / float(MY_HEIGHT);
        p->r = 0;//(unsigned char)(((cos(px + frameOffset * 10) / sin(py + frameOffset)) * cos(frameOffset * 3) * 10) * 127 + 127);
        p->g = 255;//~p->r;
        p->b = 255;
    }
}
frameOffset += 0.005f;
}
```

Sometimes the Visual Studio debugger simply exits the paint method without executing all the statements (!), sometimes there is an access violation, and sometimes everything is executed but nothing happens (the window just stays white). It never works. I based this off the code from http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/cpp/code/241875/fast-animation-with-the-windows-gdi; the code there works, but mine is apparently subtly different. A big problem for me is that I don't know how to debug the issue: I don't know how to inspect the objects, the access violation is in ntdll.dll (so no stack trace), and when it fails less spectacularly it fails silently. BitBlt is returning true (in the 1/4 runs that it actually is called). I tried calling GdiFlush before and after the onFrame() call, but that didn't really help. What on Earth could be causing this issue?